# Web hosting and CMS for twitter bootstrap site

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am starting a new project for a Custom Home Building company's website.  I am new to web development but I have programming experience, so please excuse my newbie questions.

Here is what I have been trying to find answers to, but to no avail...

I am planning on using Twitter's Bootstrap to design the website which will mostly consist of images, videos,a contact page and portfolio (pretty basic).  I am also planning on purchasing a bootstrap theme to get started and modify from there (a theme from a site called "wrapbootstrap").  Does anyone have any good experience with using Bootstrap themes and does this sound like a solid plan of action?

I am planning on using the Bootstrap theme but I am worried about content management. I would like the client to be able to change out and modify pictures and edit text easily.  Is it good practice to give clients a CMS on the site to be able to do this or is this unheard of?

Also one last question. I am planning on hosting this on GoDaddy, does the host I choose need special requirements to host a Bootstrap site or can I easily upload it to a GoDaddy host?

All help is very much appreciated, Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GoDaddy, if you Google it, has notoriously slow and lousy hosting. You should familiarize yourself with what Bootstrap is. It's simply html, css, and jQuery, so any host will work. But a CMS has specific requirements, some require php 5+, image manipulation, and other server side apps, RAM requirements, and so on. Therefore you need to figure out a good host for your CMS.

If you are good with your CMS and understand html, and CSS and some jQuery then you can take a pre-created theme or your own and put in the tags, loops, menu, footer, header, and other includes and create a database driven site. Most developers use a CMS to allow customers the ability to add content to their sites. Wordpress developers create admin themes in html, css, and php so it's easy for their customer to update.

There's also hosted CMS systems that have built in functions for nearly all the common functions like galleries, blogs, etc., you need to look around. http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/web-development/hosted-cms/

Comment: I guess my next question would be...how do I incorporate a CMS into a custom Bootstrap theme?  From the link you sent me, most of these CMS services have pre-designed templates (some with hosting included).  Am I limited to those templates for a CMS or can I implement the Bootstrap theme I buy into a CMS?

Comment: You'd have to learn the CMS to learn how to incorporate your own theme -- whether it's based on Bootstrap, Foundation, or your own solution. The most popular CMS is Wordpress, there's plenty of books, videos, and so forth on that. I doubt any hosted CMS system requires that you use only their templates, but you'd have to look at the features of their specific service. You need to learn a lot, I suggest http://teamtreehouse.com/

Comment: I think you gave me a good idea of where I need to go from here.  I am just going to use SquareSpace with one of their pre-designed templates.  Thank you Christina for reminding me that there actually are dumb questions! :)